# R - replace column values by numeric values of the same column using specific criteria

Tags: r

I want to do a particular task in R studio. I have a data-frame, which has 317 observations, of which one column is "Date". The Date column looks as below:

```
 S.No.      Date 
  1      01-05-17
  2         a 
  3         a 
  4         a 
  5      02-05-17 
  6         a 
  7         a 
  8      04-05-17 
  9         a
```

Now what I want, is to replace all character "a" with the date mentioned previously. So, `Date[2:4]` should be replaced by `Date[1]` , `Date[6:7]` should be replaced by `Date[5]` and so on.

I am trying to use `grep` and `gsub` for finding and replacing a pattern but no luck till now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to convert the `a` entries in your Date column to NA and then use `na.locf` (last observation carried forward) function from the `zoo` package.

```
df$Date <- zoo::na.locf(replace(df$Date, df$Date == "a", NA))
```

Note that you need to convert to actual `Date` format using `as.Date` afterwards unless you want to keep it as a `character` or `factor` variable.

Comment: This totally worked. Didn't think that this could be done using a single line code. I was not aware of `na.locf` function. This doesn't even require you to replace `a` entries to NA.
Thanks!!

Comment: @Sourabh happy to hear that it works for you. As a side note, once your questions are satifactorily answered, you can say thanks by accepting the answer by ticking the green check mark and/or upvote it once you have enough reputation points.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted the answer, since i don't have enough reputation point, i am not able to upvote it.